# Is there any way to draw an image to use 4 points rather than 3 (perspective warp)

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

Drawing a parallelgram is nicely supported with Graphics.DrawImage:

```
Bitmap destImage = new Bitmap(srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height);
using (Graphics gr = new Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
{
    Point[] destPts = new Point[] { new PointF(x1, y1), 
        new PointF(x2, y2), new PointF(x4, y4)};
    gr.DrawImage(srcImage, destPts);
```

How, do you do 4 points (obviously the following is not supported, but this is what is wanted):

```
Bitmap destImage = new Bitmap(srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height);
using (Graphics gr = new Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
{
    Point[] destPts = new Point[] { new PointF(x1, y1), new PointF(x2, y2),
        new PointF(x3, y3), new PointF(x4, y4)};
    gr.DrawImage(srcImage, destPts);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Closest I can find is [this information](http://vckicks.110mb.com/image-distortion.html), which is extremely laggy.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would do this with a 3x3 Matrix, but the Matrix class only lets you specify 6 values instead of 9.  You might be able to do this in Direct X.

Answer (score 0):

When thinking of how 3D tools would handle it... try drawing a triangle of one half and then the other triangle for the other half. So if you have points A, B, C, & D; you would draw (with a clipping plane) A, B, C and then B, C, D, or something of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following article in CodeProject:
[Free Image Transformation By YLS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36145/Free-Image-Transformation)
[image]

needs some works

maybe you can use this :)